# Writing a string backwards my way, sometimes results into extra output, related to the character ' w '

Tags: c++, string, iostream

This has been boggling me, the simple code:

```
int main()
{
    typedef std::string::size_type stype;
    std::cout << "What is your first name?\n";
    std::string first,second,fullname;
    std::cin >> first;
    std::cout << "What is your second name?\n";
    std::cin >> second;
    char * backwards;
    fullname = first + " " + second;
    stype fnsize = fullname.size();    
    backwards = new char [fnsize];
    stype b = 0;
    for(stype a = fnsize; a != 0; --a)
    {
       backwards[b++] = fullname[a - 1];
    }
    std::cout << backwards << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Works most of the time, but when I write a name like my own, *stanislaw terziev*, I get an output *veizret walsinatsslaw* instead of *veizret walsinats*

Why is it so?

Comment: You obviously know about `std::string`, why are you using `char*` and `new`? You might also look into standard library functions such as [`std::reverse`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems in your code.

First, you want `backwards` to be `fnsize + 1` to allow for the end of string termination (required for a C-style string, not included in the `std::string::size()` method return value).

Second, make the last element of `backwards` a `'\0'` character (the end of string character).  Without this, `std::cout` does not know where the char* 'ends' so you will sometimes get garbage characters.  That is to say std::cout will keep outputting characters until it hits a `'\0'`.

A couple of other options you could look at as well:

1. Make backwards a `std::string` and use `append(fullname[a-1])`
2. Use `std::reverse`

Answer (score 6):

I guess you forgot null terminator `'\0'`, you need to:

```
backwards = new char [fnsize+1];
backward[fnsize] = '\0';
```

Comment: Yes that was it. However I am curious as to why it presented itself only sometimes. Could somebody explain in a noobfriendly way please?

Comment: @StanislawT It's called *undefined behavior*. Situations like this cause it and it's possible that nothing can happen as a result.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this much more cleanly without managing memory (or worrying about the nul terminator) yourself:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "What is your first name?\n";
    std::string first, second;
    std::cin >> first;
    std::cout << "What is your second name?\n";
    std::cin >> second;
    std::string fullname(first + " " + second);
    std::string backwards(fullname.rbegin(), fullname.rend()); // use reverse iterator
    std::cout << backwards << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I wish I could downvote this. I really did not care for a more effective or appropriate way to do this. The question was "Why this happened?", not "How shall I improve my code?".

Comment: So my answer didn't fix your problems with nul terminating by removing the need to nul terminate?

Comment: No where in your question does it say, please maintain the manual memory management, or that you did not want to use a std::string in the reversal. So there is no problem wih my answer, your question was simply not specific enough.

Comment: My problem was that I did not understand what caused the wierd behavior. That is why I asked "Why?".